# In a $T_0$ space the union of two scattered sets is scattered

Tags: general-topology

A **scattered space** if a space $X$ that contains no nonempty [dense-in-itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself) subset.  Equivalently, every nonempty subset $A$ of $X$ contains a point isolated in $A$.

Note that in general the union of two scattered sets is not scattered.  For example, if $X=\{a,b\}$ with the indiscrete topology, $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are both scattered, but their union, $X$, is not scattered as it has no isolated point.

It is shown in Kuratowski's book (p. 79) that in a $T_1$ space, the union of two scattered sets is scattered (he assumes spaces are $T_1$ unless mentioned otherwise).  I think the following is more generally true:

> **Theorem:** In a $T_0$ space, the union of two scattered sets is scattered.

How can this be proved?

Comment: What's the idea behind Kuratowski's original proof? Knowing how to solve this for the $T_1$ case might make the $T_0$ case easier (I cannot figure out either as of yet)

Comment: @BrandonduPreez Kuratowski deduces it from another result: In a dense-in-itself space, every scattered set is nowhere dense, and the complement of a scattered set is dense-in-itself.  I have not checked if that holds in T0 spaces, finding it easier to just prove the union result directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, and a number of similar results, are proven in *Scattered spaces, compactifications and an application to image classification problem* by M. Al-Hajri et. al.

The proof they give is roughly as follows:
Let $A$ and $B$ be scattered subspaces, and $S\subseteq A\cup B$. We show that $S$ has an isolated point. Let $S_A \ = S\cap A$ and $S_B = S\cap B$, and note that $S_A$ and $S_B$ are scattered. Since $S_A$ is scattered, there is an $a\in S_A$ and and an open set $U$ such that $\{a\} = S_A\cap U$. If $U\cap S_B = \emptyset$, we're done.
So assume not. Since $U\cap S_B \subseteq S_B$, it has an isolated point. So there exists $b$ in $U\cap S_B$ and an open set $V$ such that $\{v\} = U\cap S_B \cap V$.

Thus the open set $U\cap V$ is either $\{b\}$ (in which case we're done), or $U\cap V = \{a,b\}$, in which case we use the fact that our space is $T_0$ to isolate one of $a$ or $b$, completing the proof.

Comment: Thanks Brandon for your answer and for the reference.

Comment: (your answer is basically the same as mine, but I had mine hidden to solicit more answers. thanks again)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is $T_0$.  Let $A$ and $B$ be two nonempty scattered subsets of $X$ and assume by contradiction that $A\cup B$ is not scattered.  So we can find a nonempty $C\subseteq A\cup B$ with $C$ dense-in-itself.

$C$ cannot be entirely contained in $B$, otherwise it would have an isolated point.  So $C\setminus B$ is a nonempty subset of $A$ (scattered) and has an isolated point $a$.  There is an open nbhd $V$ of $a$ such that $V\cap(C\setminus B)=\{a\}$.

But $a$ cannot be an isolated point of $C$.  So $V$ meets $C\cap B$, which must be a nonempty subset of $B$.  Since $B$ is scattered, $C\cap B$ has an isolated point $b$.  So we can find an open $U\subseteq V$ such that $U\cap(C\cap B)=\{b\}$.

- Case $a\notin U$.  Then $U\cap C=\{b\}$ and $C$ has an isolated point.  Contradiction.
- Case $a\in U$. Then $U\cap C=\{a,b\}$.  Since $X$ is $T_0$, there is an open set containing one of the points and not the other.  Intersecting further with $U$ shows that one of the two points is isolated in $C$.  Again, contradiction.